# VIM regex - match all words equal to one under cursor, except one currently under the cursor

Tags: regular-expression

I need to create regex in VIM (for plugin purpose) which would work as follows:

## Expected behavior:

`||` characters indicate current cursor position, bold words indicate matching words

---

Example nr 1:

1. foo **bar** foo **bar**
2. foo b|a|r foo **bar**
3. foo **bar** foo **bar**

Two `bar`s from first line match. First `bar` from the second line does not match because the cursor is currently placed on it. Second `bar` in the second line do match. Two `bar`s from third line match.

---

Example nr 2:

1. **foo** bar **foo** bar
2. **foo** bar **foo** bar
3. fo|o| bar **foo** bar

Two `foo`s from first line match. Two `foo`s from the second line match. First `foo` from the third line does no match as the cursor is currently placed on it. Second `foo` from the third line do match.

---

So I was tinkering a bit with it and I managed to create the regex which will match all words like one under the cursor:

```
" putting word under cursor into variable
let current_word = expand('<cword>')
" regex matching all words like one under cursor
'\k*\<\V'.current_word.'\m\>\k*'
```

**I can not figure out how to exclude word under cursor from matches.**

I found this special character `\%#` which according to VIM help

> Matches with the cursor position. (...)

Yet I couldn't figure out how to use it in my case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\%#` will always track the cursor's position, but it will only work when matching text **in the window**.  If that's what you want, this is the pattern to use:

```
\%(\k*\%#\k*\)\@!\<bar\>
```

It matches any `bar`, but excludes *any* word that's under the cursor.  Using this in a `/` search will jump to the first match, which will seem strange if the cursor is currently over `bar`.

You can use this pattern in `:match` if you just want to highlight all occurrences of `<cword>` that aren't under the cursor:

```
autocmd CursorMoved * execute 'match Error /\%(\k*\%#\k*\)\@!\<' . expand('<cword>') . '\>/'
```

If you want to match `<cword>` *at the time* of the search, you will need to create a more complicated pattern:

```
function! s:search_allbut_cword() abort
  let p1 = searchpos('\<.', 'nbcW')
  let p2 = searchpos('.\>', 'ncW')
  return '/\%(\%' . p1[0] . 'l'
        \. '\%>' . (p1[1] - 1) . 'c'
        \. '\%<' . (p2[1] + 1) . 'c\)'
        \. '\@!\<' . expand('<cword>') . '\>' . "\<cr>"
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> <leader>* <sid>search_allbut_cword()
```

`p1` is the position at the beginning of `<cword>` and `p2` is the end.  With those, it creates a pattern that matches `<cword>` *except* on the current line between two columns.  This slightly flawed since it doesn't accurately account for changes made in the excluded region.

Comment: If anyone wondering I needed it to create [this plugin highlighting word under cursor](https://github.com/dominikduda/vim_current_word).